# How to make an HTML element sit to the left of parent container?

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular app, I have an HTML parent containing child items like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

I want `child2` and `child3` to be inside `parent`, aligned left. But I want `child1` to be just to the left of `parent`. I know one solution would be to declare `child1` before `parent`, but I want `child1` to still be declared inside `parent`. I also don't want to use Javascript to find the width of `child1` and offset it with that; I want to just use CSS.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: some visuals for this would help and the current css you have

Answer (score -1):

The only practical method for a child of **unknown** width is absolute positioning.

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: .25em;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child3">Child 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this, if you don't want use flexbox:

```css
    *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:3px solid red; 
  position:relative;
}
.child1 {
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:absolute;
  left:-100px;
}

.child2 {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  float:left;
}

.child3 {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background:orange;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child3">Child 3</div>
</div>
```